# C# WPF Resizing Controls In Grid Row to Fill All Width

Tags: wpf, grid, resize, width, row

I am trying to have my ComboBox stretch to use all empty space in the expanded window. If the window's width were to shrink, the ToolBarTray will collapse.

I used a grid with 2 columns with width specified as * & 300 respectively.
How can the ComboBox be made to fill all available space in the row?

[image: Expanded window]
[image: Collapsed window]

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" Grid.Row="0">
        <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="300" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <ToolBarTray DockPanel.Dock="Left">
                <ToolBar Name="Standard">
                    <Button Height="32">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5,0,5,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                            <Image Height="24" Width="24" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Source="Images/document.png" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Button>

                    <Button Height="32">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5,0,5,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                            <Image Height="24" Width="24" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Source="Images/document.png" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Button>

                    <Button Height="32">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5,0,5,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                            <Image Height="24" Width="24" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Source="Images/document.png" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Button>
                </ToolBar>

                <ToolBar Name="Standard2">
                    <Button Height="32">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5,0,5,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                            <Image Height="24" Width="24" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Source="Images/document.png" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Button>

                    <Button Height="32">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5,0,5,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                            <Image Height="24" Width="24" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Source="Images/document.png" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Button>

                    <Button Height="32">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5,0,5,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                            <Image Height="24" Width="24" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Source="Images/document.png" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Button>
                </ToolBar>
            </ToolBarTray>

            <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" MinWidth="200" ></ComboBox>
        </Grid>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2):

use HorizontalAlignment="Strech"

See following code

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="1" MinWidth="200" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"></ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, if you want the Toolbar to totally collapse, the only solution I found was writing a little bit of code.
Having layout only in XAML would have been more elegant, but sometimes C# code is the only way.

1. Get rid of the Grid   :
2. Handle the resize of canvas :

   ```
   private void ToolbarSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
   {
       const double COMBO_MIN_DESIRED_WIDTH = 300.0;
       Size newSize = e.NewSize;

       Size sizeToolbarTray = new Size(Double.PositiveInfinity, newSize.Height);
       // measure to update DesiredSize
       toolBarTray.Measure(sizeToolbarTray);

       Rect toolBarTrayRect = new Rect(0, 0, 0, newSize.Height);
       Rect comboRect =new Rect(0,0,0,newSize.Height);

       // 3 cases :

       // 1) Much space is available
       if (newSize.Width > toolBarTray.DesiredSize.Width + COMBO_MIN_DESIRED_WIDTH)
       {
           toolBarTrayRect.Width = toolBarTray.DesiredSize.Width;
           comboRect.X = toolBarTrayRect.Width;
           comboRect.Width = newSize.Width -toolBarTrayRect.Width;

       }
       // 2) Space to show Combo, but not totally toolbar
       else if (newSize.Width > COMBO_MIN_DESIRED_WIDTH)
       {
           toolBarTrayRect.Width = newSize.Width - COMBO_MIN_DESIRED_WIDTH;
           comboRect.X = toolBarTrayRect.Width;
           comboRect.Width = COMBO_MIN_DESIRED_WIDTH;
       }
       // 3) Not enough space to show toolbar
       else
       {
           toolBarTrayRect.Width = 0;
           comboRect.Width = newSize.Width;
       }
       // Layout the two components :
       toolBarTray.Arrange(toolBarTrayRect);
       combobox.Arrange(comboRect);
   }
   ```

Here is a link to a workiing solution so that you cann check it ''s what you want :
http://1drv.ms/1MySnde

Hope I understood you wishes and it helps, regards

Answer (score 0):

Just change your column widths definition :

```
    <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

By default the ComboBox has horizontal and vertical alignments set to Stretch.

May be for the first column you could put a hardcoded size.

But if you GUI needs to have more space to be nicer, put some margins around the ToolbarTray and ComboBox

Regards

Comment: Using `Width="Auto` prevents the ToolBarTray from collapsing properly.

Eventually what I did was specify `Width="*" MaxWidth="400"` and `Width="*" MinWidth="500"` for respective columns.
Its a workaround where I have to find the absolute width of the ToolBarTray, say 400 and set as MaxWidth. Not the best way since adding new items to ToolBarTray means finding absolute width again. Was hoping there is a better solution.

Comment: I gave a try to your code ith my solution, and it seems to be fine. I can resize the toolbars, and there is no extra space on right. What is exactly the collapsing problem ? Here is my solution http://1drv.ms/1LInfDa for comparing

Comment: [link](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=2BD0338CF8FC5F36!42820&authkey=!ACAUjgfs1ZBLmrs&ithint=file%2czip)
Here is my sample solution. As window's width is decreased, the ComboBox pushes the ToolBarTray, collapsing the buttons.

Comment: Ok, I downloaded your code, and for me, it's fine, I would  not change anything ! ;-) Is the thing you want : "At least 300 dpi for the combobox

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way to have e.g.: a TextBlock using more columns in a certain row is to use Grid.ColumnSpan="7". This works perfect for situations like this:

[XAML View Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bskfh.png)

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="30" />
        <RowDefinition Height="40" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="70" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="60" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="60" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="7"
        Text="{translation:Translate PDFExportSetResolution}"
        Grid.Column="0"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        Margin="5"
        TextWrapping="NoWrap"
        Width="Auto" />
```